# Given a value, search for an adjacent key:value in an object

Tags: javascript

Given a data structure like this:

```
var userList= [    
    {
       employeeId: 10,
       name: "Bill",
    },
    {
       employeeId: 12,
       name: "Tom",
    },
    {
       employeeId: 14,
       name: "Sue",
    },
]
```

And an input of `10` how can I find the value `Bill`?

So, in other words, given a value that pairs with another Key: Value in an array of objects, how might I search for the other keys/values within that object?

I'm guessing step 1 involves searching for the value within each object in the array and step 2 involves returning the index of the object within the array meaning step 3 would be mapping to that index somehow.

EDIT: So, I ultimately just used a function with a `for...in` loop to solve this problem as shown below. While I may have done a particularly poor job of articulating my problem I was trying to take an input of an employee number and match it with an employee's name. The `for...in` loop seems to be the simplest I can find but I was looking for a more elegant object method or some such to find it. Cheers!

```
function personLookup(x){
    for (i = 0; i<userList.length; i++){
        if (userList[i].employeeID== x){
            return userList[i].name;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: You've only got one object, so what's the problem? What are you actually asking?

Comment: Should have noted that this object is one of a few dozen within an array.

Answer (score 6):

Arrays have a `.find` function which can be used to look for an element that matches a certain condition. So to find the person with employeeNumber 10, you can do the following:

```js
let employees = [{
  name: 'Jill',
  employeeNumber: 9
}, {
  name: 'Bill',
  employeeNumber: 10
}];

let numberTen = employees.find(function (person) {
  return person.employeeNumber == 10;
});

if (numberTen !== undefined) {
  console.log(numberTen.name)
}
```

Note that `.find` is appropriate if you want exactly one result, but if there are possibly multiple that match the criterion you're looking for, `.filter` is a better choice.

See documentation for these at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Thank you, I've updated my code and question for clarity because I'm ultimately not searching within an Array, but rather an Array of similar objects.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but i don't understand your new question. the data you describe is not valid javascript or json syntax.

Comment: You are correct... This is why I shouldn't have hurried. Updated with my current best solution and better formatting. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```js
let person= {
    "name" : "Bill",
    "employeeNumber" : 10
}

for(let element of Object.keys(person)){
    if(person[element] == 10){
        console.log(element);
        console.log(person.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe they are looking for `Bill`

Comment: it should be person.name

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple number 10s in your data, you can use `.filter`

```
let employees = [{
  name: 'Jill',
  employeeNumber: 9
}, {
  name: 'Bill',
  employeeNumber: 10
}, {
  name: 'Billy',
  employeeNumber: 10
}
}];

const employData = employees.filter(employee => employee.employeeNumber == 10)
if(employData.length > 0){
    console.log("names are ", employData.map(employee => employee.name))
} else {
    console.log("no employ found")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the `for...in` loop seemed to be the easiest in the long run.

https://codepen.io/mizzoudavis/pen/pWNvxw

```js
var userList= [    
    {
       'employeeID': 10,
       'name': "Bill",
    },
    {
       'employeeID': 12,
       'name': "Tom",
    },
    {
       'employeeID': 14,
       'name': "Sue",
    },
]
var x;
$('#submit').click(function(){
    x = $('#empID').val();
    personLookup(x);
})

function personLookup(x){
    for (i = 0; i<userList.length; i++){
        if (userList[i].employeeID== x){
            $('div').text(userList[i].name);
        }
    };
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="empID"/>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
<div></div>
```